# SQL Server connection-specific variables

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm upgrading my application to use stored procedures rather than dynamic SQL as it is now. What I'd like to do is call some procedure, for example setUser(id), and then for that ID to be carried forward for the duration of the current connection. I have a UserVariables table which stores important data related to the current user (I'm not using the session to store this data as the session only lasts for so long; this way the users data is persisted across logins). I want to select data, such as the ID of the client they're currently viewing, without having to pass the user ID into each stored procedure. Call it laziness, if you like!

I've searched for this quite a bit, and looked at various articles, but they're all about either global variables (which we can't change) or something unrelated.

Basically what I want to do is set the user ID at the beginning of the page load (may even move this into the session_start method at some point) and then access this variable during all subsequent stored procedure calls or queries.

Edit: What I'm after is like when you set a variable at the beginning of an asp page (my application is written in good ol' classic asp) and you then use it throughout the page and any includes. Think of the asp page representing the connection and the includes representing the stored procedures, if you like.

Comment: You can look at `CONTEXT_INFO`

Comment: @Oded - `SET CONTEXT_INFO` and `SELECT CONTEXT_INFO()` don't require any particular permissions AFAIK and meets the requirement to maintain a value for the "duration of the current connection"

Comment: What I'm after is like when you set a variable at the beginning of an asp page (my application is written in good ol' classic asp) and you then use it throughout the page and any includes. Think of it as the asp page representing the connection and the includes representing the stored procedures, if you like. I don't believe I can set the user ID, which is taken from a table, using context_info().

Comment: OK I am going to call this lazy and not even good design.  Why chance a stored procedure has a reference to the right value when you have the value to pass to the stored procedure?  And it complicates testing.  For each test you need to run  setUser(id) then the parameter less SP.

Comment: ok, so in an ASP page, if you set the session variable for a user when they initially log in and never after that, that is also equally as lazy. You're relying on nothing altering this value after logging in. I will make sure that, when the user logs in (using Windows Auth), the username is looked up in the DB and the user ID related to that username is retrieved. Besides if the user ID is not set or doesn't have sufficient permissions, it simply won't run any queries for which permissions are required - updating client information, for example.

Comment: If the userID is not set then why even run the SP?   You can still enforce permission if you pass the ID.   And why are holding on to a connection?   Why trust you have correct copy of a variable on the other end when you can just send it?   How does that simplify your ASP.NET code as it is not readily apparent you are getting information for a specific ID?   For sure it does not simplify your SP.

Comment: Blam - the user ID will ALWAYS be set. It is the first thing which is looked up in the DB. When a user first logs in via Windows Auth, a record is added to the users table with their username so they can set up their preferences and we can set their permissions using the user ID. As it happens I have found a suitable alternative. In the function to which I pass the stored procedure and parameter arrays, I simply check if there is a parameter called 'userID'. If there is, I set it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a suitable alternative to setting connection-specific variables. I have a function which takes the sproc name, an array of parameter names, an array of parameter values and a variable to return (i.e. a byref variable). I have modified this function so that, when the parameters are refreshed, it checks for a userid parameter and sets it automatically if it exists. It then returns the 'retval' parameter if it exists, otherwise sets the return variable to `myCmd.execute`.